# does duckDB create a copy of an R data frame when I register it?

Tags: r, duckdb

I am trying to learn about using DuckDB in R.  In my reading of the docs and what people say online, it sounds as if, when I register a data frame as a virtual table, no copy is made.  Rather, a pointer is created that point to the data frame.

If I create a data frame, and then register it, I can query that table and find that it contains the same number of rows as the data frame.  That makes sense.

Then, if I delete rows from the data frame, and subsequently query the virtual table, I would expect to see the new, lower number of rows.  But I do not.

What happens when I register a data frame as a virtual table?

my code:

```
dt_cars <- as.data.table(cars)
dt_cars[, .N]
# 50.  so far, so good

# Gets Database Connection
conn <- dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb())
duckdb_register(conn, name = 'tbl_cars', df = dt_cars)

query <- 'select count(*) as records from tbl_cars'
results <- dbGetQuery(conn, statement = query) %>% data.table() 
results
# 50.  that makes sense

dt_cars <- dt_cars[speed < 20, ]
dt_cars[, .N]
# 38.  that worked

query <- 'select count(*) as records from tbl_cars'
results <- dbGetQuery(conn, statement = query) %>% data.table() 
results
# still fifty!`
```

I tried registering a data frame (data.table) as a virtual table in DuckDB, and then confirming that the virtual table had the same number of records as the data.table.  It did.

Then I deleted rows from the data.table, and tried to observe that the DuckDB virtual table also had fewer rows, consistent with the data.table.

But, it does not appear that this is the case.

Comment: My guess is that it isn't making a copy of the frame, it is referencing where the frame resides in memory. When you delete rows (or update data or many other operations) in R, the default operation is to copy-on-write, meaning that the new frame will be a completely new location in memory; the old location in memory remains a "frame" until R's garbage collector sweeps for objects without references to them and eventually returns the memory for use in other ways. Duckdb is retaining a valid reference to that frame in memory, so it's still a perfectly valid frame.

Comment: Since you're using `data.table`, I'll add some context: `data.table` can be much faster/more-efficient than base-R (and other dialects) because it tends to work on the table in-place, meaning it does not make a copy each time something is updated. However ... that is not the case with subsets, even when you are assigning it back onto itself with `dt_cars <- dt_cars[speed < 20,]`: the "old" `dt_cars` is still whole in memory, and the new `dt_cars` (which is a subset of the original) is a new object.

Comment: To wrap that up, I think you should differentiate between "registering" and locking to a memory location, and locking to a _symbol_. If the latter were the case, then it would always reference `dt_cars` in whatever state it may be, including error conditions like `dt_cars <- readBin(...)`, where it is nothing like a table for duckdb to query against.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I had no idea that data.table behaved in that way when subsetting, and that perfectly explains the behavior I am seeing.

Comment: They've talked about in-memory addition/deletion of _rows_, but that is a far different problem than doing so with _columns_. (Even if/when somebody figures out how to do that well, I suspect it will _not_ be the default behavior, since otherwise that would be a significant breaking change for everywhere else that assumes that behavior.)

Comment: I am reading that "DuckDB's reference to the data frame ensures that the data remains available for analysis within the DuckDB session, even if the original data frame is modified or goes out of scope in R".  I don't dislike this feature, I am just glad that I am understanding it better.  If I want changes to that virtual table, then I will need to remember to "unregister" and then "register" the data frame as a table again.

Answer (score 1):

When you filter the data.table data frame, a new data frame is created, and duckdb doesn't have a reference to the new data frame. Duckdb is still pointing to the old data frame, which won't get garbage collected because the duckdb connection keeps the reference.

So you will either need to re-register it, or create the filtered data frame in duckdb.

You can verify this is R land as well

```
dt_cars <- as.data.table(cars)
address(dt_cars)
[1] "0x12b27880"
dt_cars <- dt_cars[speed < 20, ]
address(dt_cars)
[1] "0x1291ba800"
```

notice that the two addresses are different.

You can read more about the R client here. https://duckdb.org/docs/archive/0.8.1/api/r

Comment: Thanks for showing me the use of "address" to verify that changing a data.table in this way creates a new location in memory for the data.table.